# put JWT token in header for Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, jwt, apollo

Currently if I run graphql mutations from my react app, they don't work because the authorisation token is missing from the header. I have an admin secret that I want to insert into the header but I am not sure how to do so.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache, NormalizedCacheObject } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
....
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api/graphql',
});

const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

I also have this in my Apollo.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    client: {
      service: {
        url: 'https://api/graphql',
        headers: {
          'x-hasura-admin-secret': 'xxx',
        },
      },
      excludes: ['src/graphql/index.tsx'],
    },
  };
```

How can I include the token in the header? It would be something like this:

```
'Authorization', `Bearer ${token}
```

The same API was used in another React Native project too and they had obtained the token like this:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
...
const token = await auth().currentUser?.getIdToken();
```

But I don't get how to achieve this in react.

**I also tried it like this:**

```
import { createHttpLink, InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = 'XX';
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

But I get an error here:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
```

that:

```
Type 'ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>' is missing the following properties from type 'ApolloClient<any>': store, writeData, initQueryManager
```

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

Comment: I have tried this but it gives me ```Type 'ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>' is missing the following properties from type 'ApolloClient<any>': store, writeData, initQueryManager``` on client ```<ApolloProvider client={client}>```. Either way, would using the ```admin secret``` as a token work here? @DanielA.White

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your token is stored on the client you can try this

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("id");
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: These are the imports I used to make it work `import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";`

Comment: From your post above it looks like we used different packages, I had issues with my api when I started with the imports you are using as well. `@Apollo` has multiple folders that can be accessed.

Comment: Yeah, I commented out mine and did it the way you suggested, with the same imports but still get this error. Weird. Do you know which versions you're using?

Comment: `4.0.0` Yeah that’s weird. Here’s a link to my Apollo file maybe that’ll help a little more. https://codepen.io/niles87/pen/KKzLgWb

Comment: Till this part, I don't get an error either. I only get the error on ```<ApolloProvider client={client}>``` the first client word. This is in the return part of code from the question

Comment: If you take off the type when creating the Apollo client do you still get an error?

Comment: I am not using any type now that I am trying. Updated my code too.

Comment: You don’t happen to have Apollo boost installed? Something in this link maybe helpful
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2503

Comment: I do have it installed ```"apollo-boost": "^0.4.9"```I have already tried possible solutions from this link but nothing seemed to work. If I import ApolloProvider from Apollo Client instead Apollo/react-hooks, the warning goes away but then I start getting this https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2042

Comment: Just from my experience I uninstalled apollo-boost and my errors went away that being said my errors were issues with the httpLink.